# CSRF for RESTful API

Tags: angular, .net-core, csrf, csrf-protection

As far as I understand CSRF, this is very simple scheme:

1. User (Bob) has auth cookies for MyApp.com in his browser.
2. Attacker sends email to Bob with a link to website MyApp-Crack.com with magic button "Click to win $10.000" which is button="sumbit" of a simple hidden form with action="myapp.com/user/delete-account.php" method="POST"
3. Click on this button creates POST request to myapp.com/user/delete-account.php with Bob's auth cookies.
4. Request is authenticated and desired action is executed.

Imagine MyApp.com is purely SPA with RESTful backend, url in example (myapp.com/user/delete-account.php) is rather RESTful API (myapp.com/API/delete-account.json) and is called just and only from browsers javascript (angular) or mobile app (which uses JWT).

Idea: if I add specific header in any request in JavaScript:

`headers.append('X-MyApp-Source', 'angular-app');`

and add a server side check:

```
if (user.AuthType == "cookies" && !request.Headers.Contains("X-MyApp-Source"))
{
   return (400, "Bad request, missing source header");
}
```

Is there any way how the attacker can create request with Bob's cookies WITH request header?

- MyApp.com cannot be embedded in iframe `X-Frame-Options`
- hidden html form on MyApp-Crack.com wont add this header
- javascript on different domain add header but does not send cookies

  - *this is not true. Attribute XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials: true will send cookies*.

I am not saying my idea is bulletproof, just brianstorm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why would MyApp-Crack.com not use `withCredentials: true` to send the relevant auth cookie to myapp.com? It cannot read the cookie value, but still can send it.

Also an old (or deliberately malicious) broswer plugin or extension (old version of Java, Flash, etc.) can be used to add the header. It is about the same as the Referer/Origin check to protect against CSRF - much better than nothing, but not the best you can do.

So under ideal circumstances, it's not directly vulnerable, but not very robust either.

Comment: Koszonom Gabor! So, my last statement is not true. Javascript on different domain add header and does send cookies.